# tf broadcaster synchronization

Tags: ros, transform-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

supposed that i have two broadcasters that declare my robot's frame transformation (odom->base_link, base_link->base_laser), which are written in two different python files, (cuz it's convenient for me to manage the stack since the robot has many modules ); and i find the "odometry" tag just turn red and blue(error and OK) from time to time when i view the gmapping process in rviz. If i write them in the same python file, the problem is solved. I think it's a synchronization problem that the tf should be broadcasted in a same time. However, i just want to know, is there any solutions to that if I really want to write them in different python files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48342/tf-broadcaster-synchronization/) by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-11-14**:
I guess that this happens because both transformations use ros::time as source for the broadcasts timestamp - dunno what to do there, maybe you can simply check the last time stamp of one file in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the problem is not directly a synchronization problem but expected behavior given the setup you are using. There are just points in time where your transform `odom->base_link` has not been published yet for a specific time stamp but `base_link->base_laser` is there already. The easiest way to solve this is to increase the publish rate of your transforms. 30-50Hz should be fine.

Another common approach, in particular followed by [amcl](http://ros.org/wiki/amcl), is to future-date transforms. See [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35908/using-tf-to-transform-a-point/) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/FAQ#Why_do_I_see_negative_average_delay_in_tf_monitor.3F).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1